# Save image hibernate using sql (don´t hql)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I need save  **InputStream or byte[]** (profile image) in table using hibernate.
here code:

```
@Override
public void actualizarFotoPerfil(String id, byte[] image) throws CotrafaException {

    Session session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    String sql = "UPDATE TS_USU_FOTOS SET FOTO = ? WHERE CLIENTE = ?"; 
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

    Blob b = Hibernate.createBlob(image);
    query.setParameter(0, b.toString());
    query.setParameter(1, id);

    query.executeUpdate();

    session.flush();

}
```

Table in BD

```
create table TS_USU_FOTOS
(
  cliente NUMBER(8) not null,
  foto    BLOB
)
```

and error is :
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: tipos de dato inconsistentes: se esperaba NUMBER se ha obtenido BINARY
    ADVERTENCIA: /pages/common/cambiarFoto.xhtml @34,74 fileUploadListener="#{barraBB.actualizarFoto}": org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
    javax.el.ELException: /pages/common/cambiarFoto.xhtml @34,74 fileUploadListener="#{barraBB.actualizarFoto}": org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:310)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)

Comment: Why are you calling toString on your blob?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be you have `FOTO` column of type `blob`. But you pass string as parameter `b.toString()`. Try to remove `toString` and just pass `b`

Comment: try with `query.setParameter(0, b)` or `query.setBinary(0,image);` and error is: `se esperaba NUMBER se ha obtenido BINARY`.

Comment: Then looks like `FOTO` is type `NUMBER`.  We can't help you further without knowing your DB schema. But in general you need to set same types in Java as you have in database. If `FOTO` is a number then in `query.setParameter(0, value)`, `value` has to be a Number type in java (Integer, Long, etc.)

You can find mapping here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/basic3.htm

Comment: Ah ok, `CLIENTE` column is a `NUMBER` in DB but you pass `String id` as parameter. `id` needs to be a number type.